# HTACCESS rule to rewrite last part of URL

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I have an ajax plugin for searching products in my store that automatically inserts a parameter in the URL, breaking the query.

Since this "feature" is hardcoded and can't really modify the plugin myself, I would like to implement a rewrite rule in oder to make:

`https://mywebsite.com/?s=MySearchTerm&post_type=product&dgwt_wcas=1`

Become

`https://mywebsite.com/?s=MySearchTerm&post_type=product`

hence removing `&dgwt_wcas=1` from all URL's if present.

How can I setup a rewrite rule to accomplish this?

Comment: Please do some research and reading-up on this, before asking a plain “how to” question. URL rewriting is an already broadly discussed and well documented topic.

Comment: Although this should be easily fixed in htaccess, I would say you have a problem with your programming if the query string can break your programming so easily.

Comment: @imvain2 It doesn't break my program, it returns an empty query as it's not a parameter supported in woocommerce

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with this code

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)&?dgwt_wcas=[^&]+&?(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ /$1?%1%2 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thank you! I was having a hard time figuring out how to keep the first parameters of the URL while removing the last. This seems to do the job just fine.

Comment: I tried this fix but even restarting apache, the issue persists. 
Any additional step¿?

Comment: Try with the clear browser cache may be it will work for you.